# Using wget to download select directories from ftp server

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, ftp, wget

I'm trying to understand how to use wget to download specific directories from a bunch of different ftp sites with economic data from the US government.

As a simple example, I know that I can download an entire directory using a command like:

```
wget  --timestamping  --recursive --no-parent ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/
```

But I envision running more complex downloads, where I might want to limit a download to a handful of directories. So I've been looking at the --include option. But I don't really understand how it works. Specifically, why doesn't this work:

```
wget --timestamping --recursive -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/
```

The following does work, in the sense that it downloads files, but it downloads way more than I need (everything in the 2013 directory, vs just the county subdirectory):

```
wget --timestamping --recursive -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/
```

I can't tell if i'm not understanding something about wget or if my issue is with something more fundamental to ftp server structures.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: My installation's version of wget doesn't document an "--include" option, though it doesn't display any errors if I specify it.  Have you tried "--include-directories" instead?

Comment: Thanks Lotharyx, I fixed the typo, though my question still remains.

Comment: Try "--include-directories=whatever..." -- the manpage I read showed there being an equals sign.  I don't have an ftp server handy to actually try it out.

Comment: I gave that a go, without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits) it seems that the filtering functions of `wget` are very limited.

When using the `--recursive` option, `wget` will download all linked documents after applying the various filters, such as `--no-parent` and `-I`, `-X`, `-A`, `-R` options.

In your example:

```
wget -r -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/
```

This won't download anything, because the `-I` option specifies to include only links matching `/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/`, but on the page `/pub/special.requests/cew/` there are no such links, so the download stops there. This will work though:

```
wget -r -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/
```

... because in this case the `/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/` page does have a link to `county/`

Btw, you can find more details in this doc than on the `man` page:

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/

Answer (score 2):

can't you simply do (and add the --timestamping/--no-parent etc. as needed)

```
 wget -r ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county
```

The -I seems to work at one directory level at a time, so if we step one step up from county/ we could do:

```
 wget -r -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/2013/
```

But apparently we can't step further up and do

```
 wget -r -I /pub/special.requests/cew/2013/county/ ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cew/
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits), the parameters of `-I` must be absolute paths...